# Website (or other easily accessible resource) that shows images of Unicode and other encodings?

Tags: localization, online-storage, open-source

I am trying to find a website that displays an *image* of less common characters?

The reason an image is important is because an image can be displayed in any browser, on any OS, in any OS locale, whereas certain fonts and characters aren't guaranteed to be installed and displayed correctly.

#### Example

E.g. I would like to be able to search for Unicode and other codes like `1ECB0`, and see the equivalent image of that character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you need, but it is a great, searchable code directory:

[Unicode org charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)